# change stage/Textarea size with only AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I created a script that reads the capabilities of a computer,
The thing is that its only showing half of my output. When I printed out the script with labels I could change the size of the label, but im using a textarea right now.

Any ideas how to change the size of the textarea or the stage ?

Posting some of my code. Thanks

```
        var language2:String;
        if(Capabilities.language == "en"){
            language2 = "English";
        }
        else if (Capabilities.language.toLowerCase() == "sv"){
            language2 = "Svenska";
        }
        else {
            language2 = "language: Other";
        }

        var plugin:String;
        if(Capabilities.language == "true"){
            plugin = "debbuger";
        }

        else {
            plugin = "inte debbuger";
        }


        var myText:TextField = new TextField();
        myText.text = "Spelare: " + Capabilities.playerType 
        + "\n" 
        +"Spelarversion: "+ Capabilities.version 
        +"\n" 
        +"Språk: "+language2 
        +"\n"
        +"Du använder "+plugin+" versionen" 
        +"\n" 
        +"Operativsystem "+Capabilities.os ;
        addChild(myText);
```

Comment: You should format your code. That helps people help you. Also in the code you use a **TextField** and not a **TextArea**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;` can be used to make the TextField adjust its size to the text, as you can read about in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize

Comment: Awsome, looks so much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with:

```
myText.width = 200; // Or any other value
myText.height = 200; // Or any other value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
    myText.border = 1
    myText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT
```